# Spring-boot Kafka header byte[] format issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, jackson, spring-kafka

I am upgrading my spring-boot-starter-parent version from 2.1.9.RELEASE to 2.6.14. Noticed that all Kafka message header values are converted to byte[] format instead of String value. it is impacting all my consumers.
I would like to send header value in String format how do solve this ?

I tried with false and it is not working**setMapAllStringsOut(false)**

```
void
setMapAllStringsOut(boolean mapAllStringsOut)
Set to true to map all String valued outbound headers to byte[].

@Bean
MessagingMessageConverter converter() {

    MessagingMessageConverter converter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
    DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
    mapper.setMapAllStringsOut(false);
    converter.setHeaderMapper(mapper);

    return converter;
}

kafkaTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter());

Message<String> message = MessageBuilder
.withPayload(msg)
.setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, topicName)
.setHeader("name", "spring")
.setHeader("version", "2.6.14")
.setHeader("age", 20)
.build();

kafkaTemplate.send(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this option for the consumer side:

```
/**
 * Set the headers to not perform any conversion on (except {@code String} to
 * {@code byte[]} for outbound). Inbound headers that match will be mapped as
 * {@code byte[]} unless the corresponding boolean in the map value is true,
 * in which case it will be mapped as a String.
 * @param rawMappedHeaders the header names to not convert and
 * @since 2.2.5
 * @see #setCharset(Charset)
 * @see #setMapAllStringsOut(boolean)
 */
public void setRawMappedHeaders(Map<String, Boolean> rawMappedHeaders) {
```

The logic there is like this:

```
@Nullable
private String mapRawIn(String header, byte[] value) {
    Boolean asString = this.rawMappedHeaders.get(header);
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(asString)) {
        return new String(value, this.charset);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `setMapAllStringsOut(boolean)` mentions that though.

Also see more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#headers

Comment: Is there any logic in producer side? , not in consumer side, since multiple consumer has to do code change. It will be better to change in producer side

Comment: Try `setEncodeStrings(true)` on the consumer side. Apparently your consumers are not updated to the latest Spring for Apache Kafka. See its Javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by setting true to setEncodeStrings(true) to support earlier version.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#headers

[image]

```
  @Bean
    MessagingMessageConverter converter() {
    
        MessagingMessageConverter converter = new MessagingMessageConverter();
        DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper mapper = new DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper();
        mapper.setMapAllStringsOut(false);
        mapper.setEncodeStrings(true);
        converter.setHeaderMapper(mapper);
    
        return converter;
    }
```